# Splitting a 1-d numpy array from tdms file, and plot shorter time series/intervals from the original array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, split, labview

Need help to pull out a specific interval from a 1-d numpy array from a tdms file. Im able to plot the file but are unable to specify the sample interval that I want to plot. As you can see on the picture I want to plot the interval that is in green.

[image]

The amount of samles are about 35000, it is 1000 samples a second and I want to split it into 3 and plot the green areas. Lets say I want to plot the intervall [6000, to 13000] and so on. This is taken from a column of an tdms file. I can use the `numpy.split` but I don't want to split into many parts and then have to put those arrays together again. To get my wanted areas of plotting/ finding average of.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the array-subset function, give it your array, an index, and length and you will get your sub-array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this did the trick << data[start:stop:step] >>

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using Python array [slicing](http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-slice-listsarrays-and-tuples-in-python/)?

To plot an array from element 6000 to 13000 you can use the following:

```
a[6000:13000]
```

Note that the element with index 13000 will be excluded.